# SYNC Tcp connection performance issue

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to build a TCP server and client and transmit a 100.000 byte array (100 KB image is around 100.000 byte array) every 500 ms but whenever I start the program it quickly scales up to 500.000 KB on the memory(working set) column which means it uses a lot of memory.

My question is, which are my program flaws that cause this kind of memory problem and if my program is fine then is async TCP better for performance in this kind of scenario? I repeat it is just 1 client sending a 100.000 byte array to the server every 300 ms.

Server code:

```
Dim server As TcpListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 15000)
Dim serverclient As TcpClient
Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing

Dim thread1 As Threading.Thread
Dim thread2 As Threading.Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    server.Start()
    Form2.Show()
    thread1 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenClient)
    thread1.Start()
End Sub

Sub ListenClient()
    serverclient = server.AcceptTcpClient()
    thread2 = New Threading.Thread(Sub() Me.listenData(stream))
    thread2.Start()
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub listenData(ByVal st As NetworkStream)
    Sleep(200)
    st = serverclient.GetStream()
    Dim array(1100) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer = st.Read(array, 0, array.Length)
    listenData(st)
End Sub
```

Client code:

```
Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient
Dim array(1000) As Byte
Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() Me.send(stream, array))
Dim stream As NetworkStream
Sub send(ByVal st As NetworkStream, arr As Byte())
    Sleep(300)
    st = client.GetStream()
    st.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length)
    st.Flush()
    send(st, arr)
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    client.Connect("192.168.1.2", 15000)
    For i = 0 To array.Length - 10
        array(i) = 200
    Next
    thread.Start()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is listenData calling itself recursively?  That will cause *big* problems.

Comment: Yes, that is going to create an 1100 Byte array for every recursion which will use up memory quick. That's a classic memory leak and appears to be to no purpose. Is it required?

Comment: How can i fix it ? With a timer ?

Comment: I've worked with sockets a lot but not in .NET. Typically, the server blocks until there is data available from the client and then reads until there is no longer data available. [Have a look at the example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples). If you still can't make it work, I'll try to set up a test jig later.

Comment: In the client code, the send sub is also calling itself recursively, this will have the same sort of issues to it.  Though not as quick as the listenData routine since send doesn't allocate a local array.  A loop instead of a recursive call may be a solution for both, but can't really tell from the small amount of description provided.

Comment: You should *strongly* reconsider this line `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`

Comment: Instead of making infinite recursions (which will also consume memory), have a look at [loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/loop-structures).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the buffer array to the outside of listenData, make a buffer for each client and if you have one make a buffer for him and always use it.

```
Dim array(1100) As Byte

Sub listenData(ByVal st As NetworkStream)
Sleep(200)
st = serverclient.GetStream()

Dim i As Integer = st.Read(array, 0, array.Length)
listenData(st)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for taking the time and trying to answer the question. As a rule of thumb it is generally a good idea to not just describe the changes you are proposing, but actually including the code with your proposed changes in your answer.